# What does the word quote mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the word quote mean here?

When adding customer information, Waitlist Me allows users the option to quote a time or ETA and add future reservations that show up automatically in the system on the selected day.

I couldn't find a relevant meaning here http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quote or here http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quote

Comment: [**quote**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quote) *Give someone (the estimated price of a job or service)* In your MW link it's definition 3a: *to state (the current price or bid-offer spread) for a commodity, stock, or bond* extended to the more general 3b: *to give exact information on.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, **"quote a time or ETA"** means **"to tell the restaurant what time they would like their reservations to be or to give their estimated time of arrival at the restaurant."** It is an unusual use of the word "quote," and is therefore somewhat confusing, especially to non-native speakers of English.